# Anyone know of any plans to make ^ a shorthand for shared_ptr<T>?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

For example:

`shared_ptr<const shared_ptr<const int> > pp;`

is fairly intimidating... whereas

`const int ^ const ^ pp;`

is instantly reminiscent of the raw pointer equivalent

`const int * const * pp;`

Comment: Any reason why the Committee should do that?

Comment: Ugh... `shared_ptr` s to `shared_ptr` s? Why?

Comment: You could bring it up at the next standards meeting ;-)

Comment: If there is, I vote that we exterminate them.

Comment: @Billy - because confusing coworkers is fun!

Comment: I thought "instantly reminiscent" meant something you would recognize quickly.

Comment: @Captain: http://www.google.com/dictionary?q=reminiscent&langpair=en|en&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zFoaTdiCFIT78AbL3PGTDg&ved=0CBUQmwMoAA You are using one definition (the third one there), @nick is using the second definition.

Comment: What is truly intimidating is that you think you need a pointer to a pointer to a `const int`!

Comment: @Billy ONeal thanks for the link, did not know about the /dictionary feature. My understanding of the meaning and pronunciation seems fair enough.

Comment: This is why `typedef` exists! Why make it more confusing... KISS!

Comment: @JohnDibling It's just an example of how the syntax would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone missed the real reason :)

The nice notation T^ suggests action like a real pointer, which suggests conversions would work the same way. This is not the case. Templates can't support conversions. For example consider

```
T^ --> T const^
```

If you take ^ as *, this will work. However by default for a template:

```
p<T> --> p<T const>
```

will not work: templates are not covariant in their arguments. It is **not** possible to fix this in C++ AFAIK. You can handle that one conversion, but don't forget the others:

```
derived --> base
T ** --> T const * const*
```

just for example. If you want a real type system it has to be designed my mathematicians not compiler writers.

Comment: But in the particular case of `shared_ptr` you _can_ (and should be able to) convert from `shared_ptr<T>` to `shared_ptr<U>` if you can convect `T*` to `U*` which includes derived to base and addition of cv qualification including `shared_ptr< T** >` to `shared_ptr< const T* const >`. Perhaps I don't understand the point that you are trying to make?

Comment: @Charles: you understand. I'm not sure how what you claim is possible without losing track of the count for the pointer. But just consider shared_ptr<shared_ptr<T>> converting to and from shared_ptr<T*>, ignoring the possibility of losing track (I'm concerned with the typing).

Comment: and at what clean type system do you refer to ? Is Haskell type system clean for you ? what other languages do you refer to ?

Comment: For a single level of indirection, shared_ptr allows the same conversions that a raw pointer allows.  This magic comes from the design of shared_ptr.  It uses templated constructors (and templated assignment operators) to perform type conversions -- without losing count.

Answer (score 12):

No; this would be A Bad Idea.

One of the greatest advantages of C++ is that there are different ways to manage memory and other resources and you get to choose the best way in each situation.  `shared_ptr` is just one way; others include `auto_ptr`, `unique_ptr` (from C++0x), and `intrusive_ptr` and `scoped_ptr` (from Boost).

Many other libraries have their own smart pointer classes.  It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to make `shared_ptr` the "preferred" smart pointer.

The `^` symbol is already used by several other languages derived from C and C++.  C++/CLI uses it for managed handles and Objective C uses it for blocks.

Comment: Amen, brother!  Don't force your paradigms on me!  Rise up!

Comment: It occurs to me that C++ programmers might be even more Libertarian than others.

Answer (score 5):

On top of what the existing answers have pointed out, one reason why this is a Bad Idea(tm) is that `shared_ptr` isn't really something to be encouraged.

It is one type of smart pointer among several, and it has some critical shortcomings (it is *far* slower than any other widely used smart pointer, and using it can lead to memory leaks if you're not careful), and it is grossly overused.

What should be encouraged is the use of RAII *in general*: whether that is done through the use of various smart pointer classes (including, but certainly not limited to, `shared_ptr`), or through your own RAII wrappers around resources or by using the standard library containers is irrelevant. They key is to rely on RAII for resource management.

But a syntax such as this would elevate `shared_ptr` to some special status where it is *more* important than `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr` and all the other extremely useful examples of RAII in the standard library.

That would be misleading, and is only going to exacerbate the ridiculous over-reliance many people already have on `shared_ptr`.

I generally consider `shared_ptr` a last resort only. When possible, I prefer *any* of the other smart pointer classes, and only if none of them will do the job, do I consider using `shared_ptr`. Bjarne Stroustrup has said something similar about shared ownership in general. Ideally, your code should have stricter ownership semantics. `shared_ptr` is just there to take the last few cases where shared ownership really is the best (or least bad) option.

Another, more objective, reason, is that C++ draws a clean line between "core language" and "library". For something like `int ^` to be valid, `^` must be given special treatment in the core language, the same way that `*` is.

So `shared_ptr` would no longer be a library component, but a core language feature.

The standard committee tries to avoid that as much as possible, using the rule of thumb that anything that *can* be implemented as a library *should* be implemented as a library. And if it *can't* be implemented as a library, perhaps, instead of adding it as a core language feature, it'd be better to add something more general to the language which would allow it to be implemented as a library.

But `shared_ptr` can be implemented perfectly well as a library component. There'd be very little to gain from elevating it to the core language.

Answer (score 3):

Probably won't be done, if nothing else because Microsoft already uses `^` in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely. C++ is already an intimidatingly complex languages and adding one more feature with potential ambiguities (XOR operator already used) + the fact that Microsoft's CLI version of C++ uses this syntax for managed references -> chances for it happening are close to zero.